Using LogMetric in Azure Functiion App 8 isolated ambigous call
I have moved some old function apps to a new function app. However it seems like the is some dependency problems. When calling log metric I get following error:
!The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerExtensions.LogMetric(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger, string, double, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object>?)' and 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerExtensions.LogMetric(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger, string, double, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object>)'"
Any suggestions how to fix this?

What do you mean by moved old function apps to new function app. did you migrate from lower version to newer version? if yes, share mode details on this?

I simply created a brand new function. Its running in 8 isolated mode.

Can you share your function code?

This error typically occurs when there are multiple overloads of a method available and the compiler cannot determine which one to use based on the provided arguments. @ThomasSegato
